# Detect File system change in the path

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, filesystems, mount, mount-point

Suppose I mount a file system  (wrapfs) at path **/mnt/xyz** ---> wrapfs
and my root file system is mounted at **"/"** and is **ext3**

So if I do open on a file with path **"/mnt/xyz/file1"** how does the mount point change be detected by VFS.

Comment: read http://git.fsl.cs.sunysb.edu/?p=wrapfs-latest.git;a=blob;f=Documentation/filesystems/wrapfs.txt , or look at the source: http://download.filesystems.org/wrapfs/patches/

Comment: You want to track filesystem change from user-space, right? If so, look at [inotify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) mechanism.

Comment: There is no _mount point change_ at the time of _open_; the change happened at the time of _mount_.